# « Pays de has been là » : sens ?

Tags: sens, expressions, anglicismes

Dans un texte de l'utilisateur FSE 20goto10 on trouve le bout de texte « [pays de has been là](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=56664247#56664247) ».

> Ce que je dirais aux Européens c'est de cesser de vous inspirer de ce pays de has-been là. Ce n'est plus un modèle depuis longtemps déjà.

Il est évident qu'il s'agit de l'anglais « has been » utilisé depuis tout récemment en français (de France et d'ailleurs, je présume, puisque il n'y a aucune spécification de région dans la référence ci-dessous).

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/has-been)) (Anglicisme) (Péjoratif) Personne qui a été célèbre et qui est passée de mode.

Comment comprendre la combinaison avec « là » étant donné qu'il n'y a pas de trait d'union. On se demande si un connexion quelconque existe avec le « [dasein](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasein) » de Heidegger, qui se traduirait quand même par « être-là » (trait d'union), ou si tout simplement il s'agit d'un « là » de sélection, auquel cas on attend un trait d'union.

De plus, comment expliquer « pays de personnes célèbres passées de mode » ? Il est très peu question de mode lorsque l'on considère les personnalités culturelles, politiques et autres dans un pays donné ; l'évaluation de leur apport à une civilisation quelconque est une valeur durable. Comment comprendre ce bout de texte ?

Answer (score 3):

***Ce pays de has-been*** signifie qu'on y trouve des has-been<sup>1</sup>, des personnes qui ne sont plus des modèles, des références dans leur domaine. Ce sont des personnes dépassées. Il ne faut pas prendre les définitions au pied de la lettre. *Passé de mode* ne se réduit pas à la mode vestimentaire.

***Là*** renforce simplement pays: ***ce pays-là***, comme un peu plus loin, ***ces gens-là***. Il n'y a pas de tiret parce que *là* est séparé de *pays*, sinon, il faudrait écrire *ce pays-de-has-been-là*, ce qui est un peu lourd...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Robert: [**has been**](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/has-been)

anglicisme

**nom invariable** Personne qui a eu du succès, de la notoriété et ne l'a plus (ou en a moins).

**adjectif invariable** Démodé ; ringard</sub>

Comment: Ce n'est pas du tout sur le plan de la mode vestimentaire que je comprend ce terme.

Comment: Quand tu écris *il est très peu question de mode*, tu fais allusion à quoi ?

Comment: Je fais allusion à un entichement sur le plan des affections subjectives, peu motivées par des connaissances réelles.

Comment: Is it not possible to read _has-been_ adjectivally here, corresponding to ‘that has-been country’ more than ‘that country of has-beens’? That makes more sense in context. There’s no plural _-s_, which makes it look adjectival to me (though it may just be an error), but I can’t tell if the _de_ works with an adjective in this construction or ensures that it must be read nominally.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Yes, the chatroom origin is why I wrote “(though it may be just an error)”. Wiktionnaire gives the form with the _-s_ as the standard (to the extent the word has a ‘standard’ at all) plural form, at least for the noun (and the one plural use does have it) – although one of the adjectival quotes is plural with no _-s_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Regardless of a word adjectival or substantive status, no difference in agreement exists in French. *Has-been* is listed as invariable by both the Larousse and the Robert.

Comment: Ah, then it’s just Wiktionnaire being non-standard! But my original question remains: is _ce pays de [adjective]_ possible, so that _has-been_ here semantically modifies _pays_ as an adjective (similar, construction-wise, to _rien de bon_)? Or would it have to be _ce pays [adjective]_ to be interpretable like that?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Pays de* if often followed by a word that can be both an adjective and a substantive but the substantive role is what makes sense. *Pays de X* means a country where you can find X's (e.g. *Pays de montagnes*.) Similarly, *Pays de fous* means *Pays où il y a des fous*, not *Pays fou*. Another common idiom is *Pays de merde* (shithole country) while an adjectival expression would be *Pays merdique* (shitty country).  It is not either *Pays **des** has been* because that would mean the country of all has beens.